# Android Volley - Unexpected behavior in SSL Pinning Implementation

Tags: android, ssl, https, android-volley, pinning

Asking an SSL pinning question on SO seems to be shouting into the void, but here goes...

I need to implement SSL pinning on Android, and there are a couple of requirements/constraints I'm working with:

1. It should validate the entire certificate chain, not just the leaf.
2. It needs to work with the Volley library

Based on Google's tutorials, I came up with the following implementation for creating an SSLSocketFactory:

```
CertificateFactory factory = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");

final KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
keyStore.load(null, null);    
keyStore.setCertificateEntry("leaf_cert", getCertificate(factory, R.raw.leaf_cert));
keyStore.setCertificateEntry("interm_cert1", getCertificate(factory, R.raw.interm_cert1));
keyStore.setCertificateEntry("interm_cert2", getCertificate(factory, R.raw.interm_cert2));
keyStore.setCertificateEntry("root_cert", getCertificate(factory, R.raw.root_cert));

final TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
tmf.init(keyStore);

final SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
sslContext.init(null, tmf.getTrustManagers(), new SecureRandom());

return sslContext.getSocketFactory();
```

This SSLSocket factory is used when I create a new `HttpStack` instance. Note that I listed the certs in order of their position up the chain.

To verify this code, I leveraged Google's `nogotofail` Android demo app by modifying the code in their `NoSslCertificateChainOfTrustCheckTest`. It appeared that the pinning was working, but I actually only needed to include `leaf_cert` in the `KeyStore`. Using `openssl`, I verified that the server is only sending back the leaf cert. At this point things get super weird:

- The sister iOS app my team built uses AFNetworking to do the certificate pinning heavy lifting, and it actually enforces that all four certificates be present. In other words, *it's validating the entire chain despite only getting the leaf cert back*.
- When I actually attempt to use the code in the project (which again is using Volley), I find that not only do I not need the entire cert chain, I only need to include `leaf_cert` **OR** `iterm_cert1`.

To summarize, I need answers to the following questions:

- Is my implementation of pinning actually going to do its job?
- What sorcery is needed to validate the entire chain?
- Why am I able to substitute the intermediate cert for the leaf cert, and why can I only do this using Volley and not in `nogotofail`?

Comment: "Is my implementation of pinning actually going to do its job?" -- off the cuff, I would expect any cert backed by `root_cert` to be considered valid. "What sorcery is needed to validate the entire chain?" -- a custom `X509TrustManager`, most likely, with a custom `checkServerTrusted()` implementation.

Comment: Regarding the entire chain validation, that was my instinct as well. But to your first point, trying to include only `iterm_cert2` or `root_cert` causes an `SSLHandshakeException`. How come those two are not sufficient but either of the first two are? I'm obviously very new to these concepts, so I'd appreciate any and all education on the subject.

Comment: "How come those two are not sufficient but either of the first two are?" -- that is a fine question, one that I cannot answer, sorry.